# Displacement Equation in a Vector Field

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, physics

While building a program for a college level Physics course, I have a vector field representing force such that $\vec F = F_x(x,y) \hat{i} +F_y(x,y) \hat{j}$. I am asked to create a program which shows the path of a mass $m$ with an initial velocity vector ($\vec v_o$) and position vector ($\vec x_o$) under the influence of the field.

My solution is to make the following steps:

$\vec F = m\frac{\partial^2\vec x}{\partial t^2}$ and as such $\frac{\vec F}{m} = \frac{\partial^2\vec x}{\partial t^2}$

By integration of each side, I find that the path would be

$\vec x = \frac{\vec F \Delta t^2}{2m} +\vec v_o \Delta t +\vec x_o$ Which is the same as the typical displacement equation.

My question is as follows; Is this intuitive use of calculus correct considering that $\vec F$ is position dependent, and thus time-dependent as well?

Comment: Are $F_x$ and $F_y$ constants?

Comment: @Botond, No, $\vec F = F_x(x,y) \hat{i} + F_y(x,y) \hat{j}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Newton's equation is not
$$\vec{F}=m \frac{\partial^2 \vec{r}}{\partial t^2}$$
But
$$\vec{F}=m \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$$
So you have two equations:
$$F_x(x(t),y(t))=m \ddot{x}$$
$$F_y(x(t),y(t))=m \ddot{y}$$
So your solution is not correct, because you are treating $F$ as a constant.

Comment: From a numeric standpoint (i.e. computation) If I use my solution over an iteration algorithm (Euler's Method for example), would it still yield the same curve as the parametric solution to the system of equations that would be derived from your solutions?

Comment: @BooleanDesigns It won't, of couse. But for a nice $F$ and small $\Delta t$s, it will be quite close to that.

Comment: After some revisions to the method I was using originally, I've decided to run Euler's Method to estimate the correct curves in the following way: Given that there is some $\vec F_x$ and some $\vec F_y$ for all points in the field, It would follow that $\ddot{x} = \frac{\vec F_x}{m}$ and the same would be true for $y$. From this, $\dot{x} = \frac{\vec F_x \Delta t}{m} + \dot{x_0}$. As such, the estimates should show that for some $\Delta t$, the estimates should be $x=\frac{\vec F_x \Delta t^2}{m} + \vec v_xo \Delta t + x_o$ and the same should apply to $y$. Is this a correct method?

Comment: @BooleanDesigns My homework was quite similar to yours, so I will tell you what did I do. I "separeted" the second order differential equations (Is it the correct word?) into first order differential equations: $\dot{x}=v_x$, $\dot{v_x}=f_x$, and so on. Then, I made a function, with the initial conditions as the input, which did something like this with every equation: $x=x_0+v_{x0}*dt$, $v=v_0+f(x)*dt$ and iterated it: It called itself, with the new values as initial values. Is it understandable?

Comment: Upon implementing your new method, they appear to be the same (or at least very close) for about 98% of cases, but in extremely complex configurations, my algorithm yields slight variation. As to why my method is not equivalent, I'm not quite sure yet; but your method is definitely the correct one, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is close to the [explicit Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). You can also have a look at other [numerical methods for ordinary differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations). Some of them are beneficial if your problem has a particular structure, for instance it is Hamiltonian; in that case [symplectic integrators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) might be preferred.